# Meteor mrgalaxy:stripe package not loading content security policy

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use stripe with meteor to create a customer and then charge the customer, and I added mrgalaxy:stripe. I'm following this tutorial: http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-saas-with-meteor-stripe-part-1/. After starting meteor, I get the following errors:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Refused to load the script 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined
```

Is there a workaround with manifest.json? If so, where should it be located, what should it look like, and how do I read it in?

Comment: How is your current browser policy configured (or are you using the default one)?

Comment: I added this package https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy as per the tutorial requested.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by changing app/server/startup.js from:

```
Meteor.startup( () => Modules.server.startup() );
```

To:

```
Meteor.startup( () => {
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("https://js.stripe.com/")
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("https://checkout.stripe.com/")
})
```

The helpful references to come up with this solution were:

- https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-browser-policy-package/
- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/browser-policy

Comment: Hey, Elijah, thanks for answering this! This is the correct answer/solution.

Comment: NOTE: I'm using the browser-policy package with Meteor 1.2.1 on another project and I had to change "Meteor.startup( () => {" to "Meteor.startup( function() {" to fix "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )". This may be due to me not having a package that was allowing the syntax above to be used.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `mrgalaxy:stripe` is no longer actively supported. Give [`copleykj:stripe-sync`](https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/stripe-sync) a try.